# Firefox circular-dependency hell on Linux Mint 13

Tags: software-installation, apt, firefox, dpkg, dependencies

Having difficulty re-installing Firefox, after an installation to resolve `places.sqlite` issues. It appears that I'm trapped in *circular* dependency hell.

Need to resolve firefox dependency hell to attempt to resolve Tomcat6 project dependencies (don't ask), ASAP. Have been trying for hours.

What I've done (brief)

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

**Potential error sources:**
Found in `sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support`

> dpkg: error processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/extensions', which
>   is also in package mint-search-addon 2012.05.11

So, `/usr/lib/firefox/extensions` doesn't even EXIST!
Deleted `/var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701` as per recommendations.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Outputs:

- `sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support`

  ```
  tyler@machine ~ $ sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  [sudo] password for tyler: 
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Package firefox is not installed, so not removed
  The following packages will be REMOVED:
    firefox-globalmenu* firefox-gnome-support*
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
  2 not fully installed or removed.
  After this operation, 460 kB disk space will be freed.
  Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
  (Reading database ... 
  dpkg: warning: files list file for package `mysqltuner' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
  (Reading database ... 192642 files and directories currently installed.)
  Removing firefox-globalmenu ...
  Removing firefox-gnome-support ...
  ```
- `tyler@machine ~ $ sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support`

  ```
  tyler@machine ~ $ sudo apt-get install firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Suggested packages:
    latex-xft-fonts
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
  Need to get 0 B/24.8 MB of archives.
  After this operation, 54.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
  (Reading database ... 
  dpkg: warning: files list file for package `mysqltuner' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
  (Reading database ... 192619 files and directories currently installed.)
  Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
   trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/extensions', which is also in package mint-search-addon 2012.05.11
  Selecting previously unselected package firefox-globalmenu.
  Unpacking firefox-globalmenu (from .../firefox-globalmenu_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
  Selecting previously unselected package firefox-gnome-support.
  Unpacking firefox-gnome-support (from .../firefox-gnome-support_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
  Processing triggers for man-db ...
  Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
  Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
  Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
  Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
  Processing triggers for mintsystem ...
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0~a2~hg20121027r113701-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise_amd64.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
  ```
- `sudo apt-get -f install`

  - 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 38 not upgraded

Ideas? Tomcat6 only deploys my web application successfully in Firefox, not Chrome, so I'm really hoping to resolve this dependency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Firefox is trying to do something with `/usr/lib/firefox/extensions`, which is owned by `mint-search-addon`. The fact that the directory doesn't exist is not relevant, regarding dependencies. Do you have `mint-search-addon` installed? Is your system up to date? If both are true, try purging `mint-search-addon`.

Comment: I ended up going through Synaptic, removed mint-search-addon, firefox-globalmenu, firefox-gnome-support, then issued an update, installed and that resolved the issue. Turns out I only needed to fix two broken packages.

Thank you.